# jQuery Tooltip bodyHandler not functioning in Drupal 7

Tags: jquery-plugins, drupal-7, jquery-tooltip

I am using jQuery Tooltip 1.3 and jQuery 1.7.  When I add a title attribute to my anchor tag, the tooltip functions; however, when I try to use `bodyHandler` it is not working.  I can not log anything to the console in the `bodyHandler` function, leading me to believe it is just never called.

HTML:

```
<a href="#awrap-exhibitor-listing" class="em-tooltip tooltip-directory" data-original-title="">View how your listing will appear in the directory:</a>
<div id="awrap-exhibitor-listing" class="wrap-exhibitor-listing" style="display: none; ">
<div class="em-show-directory-example">
  <div class="sd-company-booth">
    <div class="sd-company display-inline-block">1st Guard Corporation</div>
    <div class="sd-booth display-inline-block float-right">12093</div>
  </div>
  <div class="sd-address">200 Nokomis Avenue South, 4th Floor</div><div class="sd-locale">Venice, Florida 34285</div>
  <div class="sd-phone">(800) 995-4827</div>
  <div class="sd-name">Courtney Wilson</div>
  <div class="sd-phone">www.1stguard.com</div>
  <div class="sd-product">
    <strong>WILL DISPLAY:</strong> INSURANCE FOR LEASED OWNER OPERATORS - PHYSICAL DAMAGE, NONTRUCKING LIABILITY AND OCCUPATIONAL ACCIDENT INSURANCE
  </div>
</div>
<div class="em-el-categories">Your listing will display alphabetically and under the following categories: <span class="em-el-category">Insurance</span>
</div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
Drupal.tooltipDirectoryListing = function() {
  $('.wrap-exhibitor-listing').hide();
    $('.tooltip-directory').tooltip(
      {
        bodyHandler: function() { 
                  return $($(this).attr("href")).html(); 
              }, 
                showURL: false 
      }
    );
   }
```

Comment: Maybe I should note that I did remove the `.hide()` to make sure that was not the reason it was not displaying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry all.  This was due to a conflict with bootstrap.js, which also uses tooltip() but does not have a `bodyHandler`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the `$` with `jQuery`

Your code should be like that

```
Drupal.tooltipDirectoryListing = function() {
  jQuery('.wrap-exhibitor-listing').hide();
    jQuery('.tooltip-directory').tooltip(
      {
        bodyHandler: function() { 
                  return jQuery(jQuery(this).attr("href")).html(); 
              }, 
                showURL: false 
      }
    );
   }
```

Hope this works... Muhammad.

Comment: all of the code is wrapped in `(function ($) {}` so that `$` works.  The `hide()` works, and the `tooltip` works if I add a `title` tag to the anchor element; for some reason `bodyHandler` is not being called.